# A few simple questions about Grassmann numbers: commutation relations and derivatives

Tags: fermions, commutator, anticommutator, grassmann-numbers

I'm trying to learn about [Grassmann numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) from the book "Condensed Matter Field Theory" by Altland and Simons, but I am currently encountering some difficulties. I have several smaller questions which are connected.

- Does a Grassmann number $\eta_i$ and a creation operator $a^\dagger_j$ commute or anti-commute? Altland and Simons only defined $[\eta_i, a_j]_+ =0$. I would suggest to take the conjugate of this and arrive at an equation for the creation operator, but the authors refused to define a conjugation for Grassmann numbers as it can lead to some difficulties.
- The authors defined functions of Grassmann numbers by its Taylor expansion: $f(\eta) = f(0)+f'(0)\eta$. But how do I get the equation $e^{-\eta a^\dagger} = 1-\eta a^\dagger$ which I encountered in several notes? The derivative of $e^{-x a^\dagger}$ is $-a^\dagger e^{-x a^\dagger}$. So I would guess that $e^{-\eta a^\dagger} = 1 - a^\dagger \eta$. One solution would be that a creation operator commutes with a Grassmann number, but I am not sure if this holds.
- Can anyone recommend a good introduction to Grassmann numbers and their use in field theory which does not delve too deep into the mathematics but concentrates on performing calculations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. When working with superobjects (both [supernumbers](http://planetmath.org/Supernumber) and superoperators), we normally assume that they have definite Grassmann-parity.
2. The Grassmann-parity $|\hat{A}|$ of a Grassmann-even (Grassmann-odd) superoperator is 0 (1) modulo 2, respectively.
3. A supernumber $z$ can be viewed as special case of a superoperator $\hat{A}$ in the same way an ordinary number can be viewed as a operator.
4. The [supercommutator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_superalgebra) of two superoperators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ is defined as
   $$[\hat{A},\hat{B}]~:=~\hat{A}\hat{B}-(-1)^{|\hat{A}||\hat{B}|}\hat{B}\hat{A} .$$
5. We say that two superoperators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ supercommute if their supercommutator vanishes $[\hat{A},\hat{B}]=0$.
6. A supernumber $z$ supercommutes with any superoperator $\hat{A}$ that doesn't depend on $z$.
7. Point 6 implies that a Grassmann-odd supernumber $\theta$ and a Grassmann-odd superoperator $\hat{A}$ (that doesn't depend on $\theta$) have a truncated Taylor expansion:
   $$\tag{1} \exp(\theta\hat{A})= 1 + \theta\hat{A}+ \frac{1}{2}(\theta\hat{A})^2+ \ldots = 1 +\theta\hat{A}. $$
8. A superfunction 
   $$\tag{2} f(\theta)~=~\theta a + b~=~ (-1)^{|a|} a\theta  + b $$ 
   in one Grassmann-odd supernumber $\theta$ must necessarily be an [affine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) function.
9. *Left* differentiation is defined by
   $$\tag{3}  f^{\prime}(\theta)~:=~\frac{d}{d\theta}f(\theta)~:=~a~=~f^{\prime}(0).$$ 
   The word *left* here means that the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ acts on the function (2) from the *left.*
10. One can also define a corresponding right differentiation $$\tag{4}\frac{d^{R}f(\theta)}{d\theta}~:=~(-1)^{|a|} a
    ~=~-(-1)^{|f|} f^{\prime}(\theta),$$ 
    but the sign factor is less natural to work with in practical calculations.
11. Thus we may write equation (2) as a Taylor expansion$^1$
    $$\tag{5} f(\theta)~=~f(0)+\theta f^{\prime}(0)
    ~=~f(0)-(-1)^{|f|}f^{\prime}(0)\theta .$$
12. For references and more information, see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9960/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40746/2451) Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ Note that Altland and Simons (A&S), *Condensed Matter Field Theory,* (2010) p.162, has a crucial sign mistake in their analogue of formula (5). It is clear from a formula in the text between eqs. (4.14-15), that A&S are using left (as opposed to right) differentiation.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that Grassmann numbers $\eta$ are supernumbers with parity 1 and (fermionic) creation/annihilation operators are superoperators with parity 1. So, according to 5) a Grassmann number and a creation operator supercommute (in this case, anticommute). I can see how to arrive at the equation $\exp(-\eta a^\dagger) = 1- \eta a^\dagger$ with your Taylor expansion (because $-\eta$ is also a Grassmann number), but I would like to use the definition from Altland & Simons: $f(\eta) = f(0) + f'(0) \eta$ with $f(\eta) = \exp(-\eta a^\dagger)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Yes, I realized that A&S have a lot of typos and errors in their formulae.