# Canonical Quantisation vs the Dirac Field, why does it even work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator, superalgebra

Using the "Dirac Prescription", we can preserve the format of a differential equation in its QM form. If we define the canonical variables s.t. they have the same commutation relations times $i$ as the Poisson brackets, Heisenberg and Hamiltons equations will have the same form.

This gives us a very simple way to quantise a boson field: Just set the commutation relations in the right way, and Heisberg's equation will just be the wave equation. From this point everything will follow: Heisenberg equation will be Lorentz invariant if the Lagrangian is, the Noether current is conserved in the QM version of the theory. Birds will sing.

my question is: **What about the Dirac field?**

Since we are defining the anti-commutator instead of the commutator, the same logic do not apply. Anti-commutator cannot (as far as I can tell) act as a derivative on a formal series like the commutator.

So why are we justified in quantising the Dirac Field like that?

*(If you can, I would appreciate justifications that don't have anything to do with Feynman integrals)*

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The same logic still applies to [Grassmann-odd variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) with pertinent sign factors.

1. The Dirac prescription $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}\to [\cdot,\cdot]/i\hbar$ in principle also work for [supervariables](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber) (up to higher-order quantum corrections, cf. the [deformation quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization) paradigm). The relevant (graded) bracket structures $\{\cdot,\cdot\}_{PB}$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ are a super-Poisson bracket and a [supercommutator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/86995/2451), respectively.
2. The Schrödinger representation$^1$
   $$ \hat{q}~=~q  , \qquad \hat{p}~=~\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial_R}{\partial q}~=~(-1)^{|q|}\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial_L}{\partial q}, \qquad[\hat{q},\hat{p}]~=~i\hbar{\bf 1},\tag{1}$$
   also works for supervariables &  supercommutators.
3. For further details, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186952/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232382/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264022/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

--

$^1$ Here the subscript $R$ & $L$ denote left & right derivatives, and $|q|$ denotes the Grassmann-parity of $q$. NB: Apart from the explicitly written sign factor in eq. (1), there may be additional sign factors in accordance with the [Koszul sign rule/convention](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=koszul+sign), stemming from permuting Grassmann-odd objects.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have read it multiple times, but still cannot understand how this might solve the problem. 1. To get Dirac's equation, I never have to assume that the field is a Grassmann-valued-field. 2. In addition to that, I can write Classical Hamiltonians that give Heisenberg equation =! Hamilton equation (for example, $H=P$, or $H=P_1P_2$). Could you help?

Comment: 1. This is essentially asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451).