# Derivative with respect to a spinor of the free Dirac lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, fermions, differentiation, dirac-equation, grassmann-numbers

When we derived Dirac Equation starting form the lagrangian, our QFT professor said:

"let's take the free lagrangian $$\mathscr L = i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi - m\bar\Psi\Psi$$ and perform 
$$ \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\Psi)} = \frac{\partial (i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi)}{\partial (\partial_\mu\Psi)} = - i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu ,$$ 
where the extra minus sign come from the fact that when we perform the derivative with respect to $\partial_\mu\Psi$ we 'pass through' $\bar\Psi$ and the exchange of two spinors give raise to a minus sign".

This doesn't change anything in computing Dirac equation, but when I tried to compute the stress energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ I obtained (I'm using $\eta^{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(+1, -1, -1, -1$))
$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\Psi)}\partial^\nu\Psi + \frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\bar\Psi)}\partial^\nu\bar\Psi - \eta^{\mu\nu}\mathscr L = -i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\Psi  $$
since the lagrangian is zero on-shell.

Now I take the zero-zero component which is nothing but the energy density 
$$\mathscr H = T^{00} = -i\bar\Psi\gamma^0\partial^0\Psi $$
but this energy not only is different from the one I found in every book, it is also negative which means it is certainly wrong. My question now is where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are a pair of Grassmann variables, then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_2}(\theta_1\theta_2)=-\theta_1\qquad\tag{left derivative}
$$
where the negative sign is due to the fact that partial derivatives anti-commute with odd variables.

Moreover, Taylor's theorem reads
$$
f(\theta_1,\theta_2+\delta)=f(\theta_1,\theta_2)+\delta\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta_2}+\cdots
$$
where here the ordering of factors is important ($f$ is an even function).

Therefore, the correct expression of the energy-momentum tensor is
$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \color{red}{-}\frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\Psi)}\partial^\nu\Psi + \partial^\nu\bar\Psi\frac{\partial\mathscr L}{\partial (\partial_\mu\bar\Psi)} - \eta^{\mu\nu}\mathscr L = \color{red}{+}i\bar\Psi\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\Psi
$$

Note that most books use *right* derivatives, which makes this analysis simpler.

Answer (score 3):

User AccidentalFourierTransform has already given a good answer. Here we will stress a few points:

1. The main issue is that the [superdifferential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_%28mathematics%29) reads
   $$\mathrm{d}\theta\frac{\partial^Lf(\theta,\bar{\theta})}{\partial\theta} +\mathrm{d}\bar{\theta}\frac{\partial^Lf(\theta,\bar{\theta})}{\partial\bar{\theta}} ~=~ \mathrm{d}f(\theta,\bar{\theta}) ~=~ \frac{\partial^Rf(\theta,\bar{\theta})}{\partial\theta}\mathrm{d}\theta+\frac{\partial^Rf(\theta,\bar{\theta})}{\partial\bar{\theta}}\mathrm{d}\bar{\theta},\tag{1}$$
   where the order of factors depends crucially on whether one uses left or right derivatives. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86987/2451) Phys.SE post.

   E.g. the order (1) becomes important when constructing the canonical [stress-energy-momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) (SEM) tensor, which is the Noether current for spacetime translations, cf. OP's question. Another example is when constructing the Hamiltonian formalism for fermions. See e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/175928/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.
2. The other issue is that $\theta$ and $\bar{\theta}$ are strictly speaking *not* independent Grassmann-odd variables; however one may *treat* them as independent. This issue is similar to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451) Phys.SE post for Grassmann-even variables.