# Dirac Fields and Derivatives (Am I gaining extra minus signs?)

Tags: dirac-equation, noethers-theorem, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

I've given myself a severe headache jumping between East/West Coast sign conventions; I have picked up an extra minus sign and could do with a hand. I am currently using $\eta=\textrm{Diag}[-,+,+,+]$

So I have the symmetrised  Dirac Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = -i ~\bar{\psi}\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu \overrightarrow{\partial_\mu} -\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu \overleftarrow{\partial_\mu} + m\right)\psi
$$

I am considering the infinitesimal transformation:
$$
\delta \psi = i \theta \psi ; ~\delta\bar{\psi}=-i\theta\bar{\psi}
$$

Clearly we have:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\bar{\psi}} = -i\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu \overrightarrow{\partial_\mu} + m \right) \psi;~
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\bar{\psi})} = \frac{i}{2}\gamma^\mu\psi
$$

My confusion begins when I consider the derivatives w.r.t. $\psi$; I was under the impression that these Fermonic fields were Grassmann odd and therefore I pick up a minus sign as I move the derivative "through" $\bar{\psi}$. In doing this I find:
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\psi} = +i~\bar{\psi}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\gamma^\mu \overleftarrow{\partial_\mu} + m \right);~
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)} = \frac{i}{2}\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu
$$

I then find the Noether current to be:

$$
\begin{split}
J^\mu =& \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\delta\psi + \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\bar{\psi})}\delta\bar{\psi} \\
=& \frac{\theta}{2}\left(-\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi + \gamma^\mu \psi \bar{\psi}\right)
\end{split}
$$
Then:
$$
\begin{split}
\gamma^\mu \psi\bar{\psi} &= \gamma^\mu \psi \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \\
&= -  \psi^\dagger \gamma^\mu  \gamma^0 \psi \\
&= +  \psi^\dagger  \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \psi + 2 \eta^{\mu 0}\psi^\dagger \psi\\
&= +\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi
\end{split}
$$

Clearly something is wrong here. Either I made a mistake in taking the derivatives or I have messed up the rearrangement of the fields.

I ought to get the result:
$$
J^\mu \propto \bar{\psi}  \gamma^\mu \psi
$$
Some advice would be really appreciated, I've been banging my head against this for too long trying to find the erroneous minus one.

Comment: You need a relative sign between the two terms in the Noether current. You have to be careful when deriving the form of the current - you should act with $\delta\psi \frac{\partial}{\partial\left(\partial_\mu \psi\right)}$ on $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Is this due to the ordering of the $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^\mu$ matrices?  Tong has the same form as me (although I think he's using the other metric convention). Whilst changing the order fixes my issue it still leaves me with little understanding of whether  I have been doing the rest correctly.  http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/pz229/Teaching_files/QFT3.pdf

Comment: essentially the same question behind https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/301860

Comment: Ah I need to sit and rederive the form of the Noether current then? I saw that thread before but it only affirmed my notion that I was taking the derivatives correctly.