# Is the derivative with respect to a fermion field Grassmann-odd?

Tags: field-theory, differentiation, fermions, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

Fermion fields anticommute because they are Grassmann numbers, that is,
\begin{equation}
\psi \chi = - \chi \psi.
\end{equation}
I was wondering whether derivatives with respect to Grassmann numbers also anticommute, as in

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi} (\bar \psi \psi) \stackrel{?}{=}  - \bar \psi \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi} (\psi) = - \bar \psi.
\end{equation}

Comment: Yup, they are defined to anticommute.

Comment: related/possible dup.: [Derivative with respect to a spinor of the free Dirac lagrangian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301860/84967).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Since$^1$ $$(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}z)~=~1\tag{1}$$ 
   for any [supernumber](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber)-valued variable $z$, the Grassmann-parity of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ should be the same as the Grassmann-parity of $z$ in order for eq. (1) to preserve Grassmann-parity.
2. In [superspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace) $\mathbb{R}^{n|m}\ni(x,\theta)$ a [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $\frac{\delta}{\delta z(x,\theta)}$ and its superfield $z(x,\theta)$ carry the same (opposite) Grassmann parity if the number $m$ of $\theta$'s is even (odd), respectively:
   $$ (\frac{\delta}{\delta z(x,\theta)}z(x^{\prime},\theta^{\prime}))~=~\delta^n(x\!-\!x^{\prime})\delta^m(\theta\!-\!\theta^{\prime}) \tag{2}.$$

--

$^1$ The parenthesis on the left-hand side of eq. (1) is supposed to indicate that the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ does not act past $z$.

Answer (score 2):

In a Grassmann algebra (or more pedantic, a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded algebra), the expression with two equality signs you wrote is ill-defined. One either has a left-derivative, or a right-derivative, which are different operators in terms of results. More precisely,

$$ \frac{\partial^L}{\partial \psi} \left(\bar{\psi}\psi\right) = (-)^{\epsilon(\bar{\psi})\epsilon(\psi)} \bar{\psi} $$

$$ \frac{\partial^R}{\partial \psi} \left(\bar{\psi}\psi\right) = \bar{\psi} $$,

where the epsilons are the Grassmann parities of the two variables. if both variables are Grassmann-odd, then the results of the operators are different (one is minus the other).