# Grassmann confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers

I am trying to calculate $$\mathcal{\bar{D}}_\dot{\alpha}y^\mu=
\left(\bar{\partial_\dot{\alpha}}+i\theta^\alpha\sigma^\mu_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\partial_\mu\right)\left(x^\mu+i\theta^\beta\sigma^\mu_{\beta\dot{\beta}}\bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta}
\right)$$
$$
=i\theta^\beta\sigma^\mu_{\beta\dot{\beta}}\bar{\partial}_\dot{\alpha}\bar{\theta}^\dot{\beta}+i\theta^\alpha\sigma^\mu_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\bar{\theta}^\dot{\alpha}\partial_\mu x^\mu
$$
$$
=2i(\theta\sigma^\mu)_\dot{\alpha}
$$

$y^\mu$ is a transformation from the $x^\mu$ coordinate. I should have gotten $\mathcal{\bar{D}}_\dot{\alpha}y^\mu=0$ as mentioned in the notes. Is one of the 2 terms on the 2nd line negative? That would cancel out.

I suspect my mistake might be with the grassmann properties(missed a - sign).

Source: ([Bertolinis Notes on SUSY](https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/susycourse.pdf))  (section 4.4)

Comment: ${\bar \partial}_{\dot \alpha} \theta^\beta = -  \theta^\beta  {\bar \partial}_{\dot \alpha}$

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301860/84967

Comment: @Prahar isn't $\bar{\partial}_\dot{\alpha}\theta^\beta=0$ ?

Comment: what I meant was ${\bar \partial}_{\dot \alpha} ( \theta^\beta f ) = - \theta^\beta {\bar \partial}_{\dot \alpha} f$.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! Then I have a minus sign which makes the expression zero. Perfect.