# Berezin Integration, confirming an measure is invariant

Tags: coordinate-systems, integration, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

I am working through the Mirror Symmetry book, available [here](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf).

I already had a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/785336/) about an earlier part of the same Exercise 9.2.1 on page 157:

We are given the following action with one boson and two fermions ($h$ is some function of $X$):
$$\begin{align*}
S(X, \Psi_1, \Psi_2) = \frac{1}{2} (\partial h)^2 - \partial^2 h \Psi_1 \Psi_2.
\end{align*}\tag{9.29}$$

We are told to consider the following transformations:

$$\begin{align*}
X'  &= X +\epsilon^1 \Psi_1 + \epsilon^2 \Psi_2 \\
\Psi_1' &= \Psi_1 + \epsilon^2 \partial h \\
\Psi_2' &=  \Psi_2 - \epsilon^1 \partial h.
\end{align*}\tag{9.30}$$

$\epsilon^i$ and $\Psi_i$ are Grassmann odd variables, and so anticommute.

We are asked to show the integration measure is invariant. It says in doing so, we will develop a concept of superdeterminant and supertrace. I'm not sure if we are really expected to develop these notions ourselves here, but I resorted to referencing [Wikipedia: Berezin Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral)

From that wiki page:

\begin{align*} 
dX' d\Psi_1'd\Psi_2' = \frac{det(A - B D^{-1}C)}{det(D)}dX d\Psi_1 d\Psi_2
\end{align*}

where $A = \frac{\partial X'}{\partial X}$, $B = \frac{\partial X'}{\partial \Psi_j}$, $C = \frac{\partial \Psi_i'}{\partial X}$, and $D = \frac{\partial \Psi_i'}{\partial \Psi_j'}$.

I got

\begin{align*} 
dX' d\Psi_1'd\Psi_2' = (1 - 2 (\partial^2 h) \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2)dX d\Psi_1 d\Psi_2
\end{align*}

This comes from $A = 1$, $B = (\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$, $C = (\epsilon_2 \partial^2 h, - \epsilon_1 \partial^2 h)^{T}$, and $D = I_2)$.

In case it matters, I am assuming derivatives act from the right.

Have I made a calculation error? Or is there some reason why the $\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2$ term should be zero?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. It is enough to check for an infinitesimal transformation
   $$\begin{align}
   \delta x  ~=~&\epsilon^i\psi_i,\cr
   \delta\psi_i ~=~& \epsilon_{ij}\epsilon^j h^{\prime}(x), \cr
   i,j ~\in~&\{1,2\}. 
   \end{align}\tag{9.30}$$
2. In that case the [Jacobian factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) [minus 1] is given by the [supertrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertrace) of [the change in] the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)
   $$ \frac{\partial_R(\delta x,\delta\psi_1,\delta\psi_2)}{\partial (x,\psi_1,\psi_2)}.\tag{1}$$
3. If the Grassmann-odd infinitesimal parameters
   $$\epsilon^i~=~ a^i(x)\psi_1\psi_2+ b^{ij}(x)\psi_i +c^i(x)\tag{2}$$
   are non-constant functions of the variables $(x,\psi_1,\psi_2)$ [as they are on the bottom of the very same page!], then clearly the supertrace does *not* need to vanish. [That is e.g. the main point of eq. (9.34).]
4. So Ref. 1 is presumably implicitly assuming that $\epsilon^i$ are constants in Exercise 9.2.1. Then the whole diagonal of the matrix (1) [and hence the supertrace] indeed vanish.

References:

1. K. Hori, S. Katz, A. Klemm, R. Pandharipande, R. Thomas, C. Vafa, R. Vakil, and E. Zaslow, *Mirror Symmetry,* 2003; Sections 9.2-9.3. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01.pdf).