# Geometric interpretation of Grassmann variable

Tags: mathematical-physics, fermions, grassmann-numbers

[Grassmann variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number) were introduced to make path-integral formalism easier to handle fermionic (anti-commutating) fields.

Mathematically they represent the exterior algebra of forms (or exterior derivatives).

Furthermore they can be represented (matrix representation theory) as matrices of dimension $2^n \times 2^n$.

However a similar concept is found in complex numbers which have both a [matrix representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers) and a geometric one (as $2$-dimensional vectors).

> What is the geometric representation/interpretation of a Grassmann number (even in higher dimension if needed)?
>
> More specificaly what would be the geometric intepretation of
>   $\theta^2=0$?

For example a mixed number of the form $a+b\theta$ (in geometric analogy to complex number)

Comment: If you know they are essentially the exterior algebra - what more than the geometric interpretation than that of the $k$-th exterior power as $k$-planes (and thus of $\theta$ as a "line" that cannot span a plane, hence $\theta^2= 0$) do you think there is?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, yes, i was thinking sth along the lines of vectors similar to complex numbers. for example a mixed number of the form $a+b\theta$ as a vector. in effect i want to see the geometric analogy with complex numbers, if you want i can ask a converse question about complex numbers in geometric analogy with grassman numbers

Comment: Why do you think that Grassmann numbers are analogous to complex numbers? Though you can obtain both by formally adjoining an element $\mathrm{i}$ resp. $\theta$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the fact that one imposes the relation $\mathrm{i}^2 = -1$ and the other $\theta^2 = 0$ means they are fundamentally different - for instance, the complex numbers are a field extension of the reals, while the Grassmann numbers are not.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, this is the question, more about geometry that number theory

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/22247/13917 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5005/2451

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number . They are the simplest n=1 case of Grassmann numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no answer is provided thus far, I will attempt at a tentative answer along geometric lines.

The answer is based on [EPH-classifications in Geometry, Algebra, Analysis and Arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07859) and exposes a basic trichotomy in Geometry, Algebra, Analysis and Arithmetic between Elliptic equations/spaces, Parabolic equations/spaces and Hyperbolic equations/spaces (that goes back to ancient greek mathematics on classifications of conic sections).

Specificaly:

> Trichotomy of Elliptic-Parabolic-Hyperbolic appears in many different
> areas of mathematics. All of these are named after the very first
> example of trichotomy, which is formed by ellipses, parabolas, and
> hyperbolas as conic sections. We try to understand if these
> classifications are justified and if similar mathematical phenomena is
> shared among different cases EPH-classification is used.
>
> At first glance EPH-classification is nothing deep. A discriminant of
> a quadratic form being negative, zero or positive should not be that
> important for people to make so much fuss about it. Geometric
> similarity between the zeros of quadratic forms in affine space, could
> be a motivation for naming them differently. But why is it that the
> elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic names are used so widely in
> mathematics, in places where it seems irrelevant to the shape of
> hyperbola, parabola and ellipse? The question is, does there exist a
> paradigm behind these namings.

Of interest is that **complex numbers are related to elliptic spaces, dual numbers (grassmann numbers) to parabolic spaces and usual numbers to hyperbolic spaces**.

> [..]We shall justify below why ”Elements of $SL_2(R)$” are named elliptic,
> parabolic, and hyperbolic after the original paradigm of conic
> sections. ”Actions of $SL_2(R)$ on complex numbers, double numbers, and
> dual numbers” are also related to the geometry of conic sections.
>
> [..]A key part of the study of Mobius transformations is their
> classification into elliptic, parabolic and hyperbolic
> transformations. The classification can be summarized in terms of the
> fixed points of the transformation, as follows: Parabolic: The
> transformation has precisely one fixed point in the Riemann sphere.
> Hyperbolic: There are exactly two fixed points, one of which is
> attractive, and one of which is repelling. Elliptic: There are exactly
> two fixed points, both of which are neutral. Now we turn to studying
> the connection between Mobius transformations and conic sections. The
> transformations we consider are those that preserve the unit disk . It
> is straightforward to see that all such Mobius transformations
> correspond to matrices in $SU(1, 1)$. Given such a matrix , the Mobius
> transform maps the unit disk into itself in such a way that it maps
> arcs orthogonal to the unit circle to arcs orthogonal to the unit
> circle. These transforms are in fact the isometries of the Poincare
> disk.
>
> [..]The $SL_2(R)$ action by Mobius transformations is usually considered as
> a map of complex numbers $z = x + iy, i^2 = −1$. Moreover, this action
> defines a map from the upper half-plane to itself. However there is no
> need to be restricted to the traditional route of complex numbers
> only. Less-known double and dual numbers also have the form $z = x + iy$
> but different assumptions on the imaginary unit $i$: $i^2 = 0$ or $i^2 = 1$
> correspondingly. Although the arithmetic of dual and double numbers is
> different from the complex ones, e.g., they have divisors of zero,
> we are still able to define their transforms by Mobius
> transformations in most cases. Three possible values $-1, 0$, and $1$ of $\sigma = i^2$
> will be referred to here as elliptic, parabolic, and hyperbolic
> cases respectively.
>
> [..]To understand the Mobius action in all EPH cases, we use the Iwasawa
> de- composition of $SL_2(R) = ANK$ into three one-dimensional
> subgroups $A, N, K$: $\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}k & 0\\\ 0 & k-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & w\\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}Cos \theta & −Sin \theta\\\ Sin
> > \theta & Cos \theta\end{pmatrix}$.
>
> Subgroups $A$ and $N$ act in (1)
> irrespective of the value of $\sigma$: $A$ makes a dilation by $α^2$,
> i.e., $z \rightarrow α^2z$, and $N$ shifts points to left by $ν$, i.e.
> $z \rightarrow z + ν$. By contrast, the action of the third matrix
> from the subgroup $K$ sharply depends on $\sigma$. In the elliptic,
> parabolic and hyperbolic cases K-orbits are circles, parabolas and
> (equilateral) hyperbolas correspondingly.
>
> [..][Riemann’s] uniformization theorem says that every simply
> connected Riemann surface is conformally equivalent to one of the
> three domains: the open unit disk, the complex plane, or the Riemann
> sphere. In particular it admits a Riemannian metric of constant
> curvature. This classifies Riemannian surfaces as elliptic (pos-
> itively curved rather, admitting a constant positively curved metric),
> parabolic (flat), and hyperbolic (negatively curved) according to
> their universal cover. The uniformization theorem is a generalization
> of the Riemann mapping theo- rem from proper simply connected open
> subsets of the plane to arbitrary simply connected Riemann surfaces.
>
> [..]From this, a classification of metrizable surfaces follows. A
> connected metriz- able surface is a quotient of one of the following
> by a free action of a discrete subgroup of an isometry group:
> 1.the sphere (curvature +1)
> 2.the Euclidean plane (curvature 0)
> 3.the hyperbolic plane (curvature −1).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that the $(1, e) $ Grassman algebra with $e^2=0$ permits an interpretation in terms of Galilean transformations, like what the previous answer wrote. This is analogous to complex numbers

Also,the higher dimensional exterior algebra $(1, e_1, e_2, e_3.....) $ can be geometrically interpreted in terms of multivectors : oriented planes in higher dimensions. The magnitude of the wedge product is the determinant of the vectors in the wedge product.

The anticommutative structure $e_ie_j=-e_je_i$ encodes determinants. The idea is the same as in cross products: The length $|\vec{a}\times \vec{b}|$ gives you the area of the parallelogram, while the direction gives you the orientation of the parallelogram. But the cross product does not generalise to higher dimensions.

Cross product defines $e_1\times e_2=e_3$. This definition is possible in three dimensions. In higher dimensions, you don't have a unique vector that is orthogonal to both multiplicands.

Instead, we just define $e_1e_2=e_1\wedge e_2$ as a mathematical object that directly represents the orientation of the plane $(x, y) $. $e_1e_4$ represents the orientation of the plane $(x,w) $ etc. Linear combinations like $e_1e_2+e_1e_3$ represent the plane $e_1 \wedge (e_2+e_3)$.

$(e_1+e_4) \wedge (e_2+e_1) \wedge e_3$ represents a 3D parallelopiped, oriented in 4D space.